# composer update fails - image not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to run composer update on my iMac (Big Sur 11.7.6) but it is failing. Previously I was using the inbuilt php version that comes with MacOs but I now need to updgrade. I've installed a new PHP version using Xammp and changed the path and that's working fine. The problem is I think composer was trying to use the old php version before (which worked) but now isn't happy with the new version.

user@my-iMac csmwg % php -v

PHP 8.1.4 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2022 03:15:01) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans

user@my-iMac csmwg % which php

php: aliased to /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/php-8.1.4

user@my-iMac csmwg % composer update

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libunistring/lib/libunistring.2.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib/libidn2.0.dylib
Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      composer update

The old, in-build PHP version is in /usr/bin:
user@my-iMac bin % /usr/bin/php -v

WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.29-to-be-removed-in-future-macOS (cli) (built: Aug 29 2022 08:54:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.29, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

I've searched the iMac (using Finder) for the libunistring.2.dylib file it seems to want, but I can't find it anywhere. But there is a libunistring.5.dylib

I'm using the zsh shell. The .zshrc file only contains one line:

alias php="/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/php-8.1.4"

I'm using php for Laravel and running e.g. 'php artisan serve' works fine.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer, though probably not the best one. After a bit of digging through the file system I found the libunistring.2.dylib file that composer was looking for and copied into the directory where it was looking.

This hasn't really got to the root cause of the problem, but at least it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).